# Ввод переменной типа enum с клавиатуры

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс `HealthyFood` и `enum Fruits{ apple, pear, peach, orange}`. Я создаю в ранее сказанном классе переменную `fruit` типа данных `Fruits` и хочу создать сеттер для ее заполнения. Для этого мне надо как-то перегрузить оператор ввода, чтобы он строку преобразовывал в `Fruits`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте где то так

```
enum Fruits{ apple, pear, peach, orange};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Fruits& f)
{
    std::string s;
    is >> s;
    if (s == "apple") f = Fruits::apple;
    else if (s=="pear") f= Fruits::pear;
    else if (s=="peach") f= Fruits::peach;
    else if (s=="orange") f= Fruits::orange;
    return is;
}

int main(){
    Fruits f;
    std::cin >> f;
}
```

если при этом хочется ещё и выводить в "красивом виде", тогда можно дописать оператор вывода

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Fruits& f)
{
    switch (f) {
        case 0: { os << "apple"; break; }
        case 1: { os << "pear"; break; }
        case 2: { os << "peach"; break; }
        case 3: { os << "orange"; break; }
        default: {os << "------"; break;}
    }
    return os;
}
```

и теперь

```
Fruits f = pear;
std::cout << f;
```

будет работать так, как Вам хочется.

Comment: Спасибо! Еще один вопрос: решил сделать функцию, которая случайным образом выбирает фрукт
Fruits getRandomFruit() {
 switch (rand() % 3) {
  case 0: {
   return apple;
   break;
  }
  case 1: {
   return pear;
   break;
  }
  case 2: {
   return peach;
   break;
  }
  case 3: {
   return orange;
   break;
  }
 }
}
Но возвращает адрес, а не фрукт. Разыменование не работает

Comment: это не адреса возвращаются. В enum у каждого элемента есть id - некое число. Их Вы и видите. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: С массивом структур не лучше будет?

Comment: можно по разному. Мы все ещё ждем, когда для enum впилят подобную функциональность "из коробки". Но пока все proposals сильно простенькие и коммитет (и сам Страуструп) их отвергает.